# Javascript: Need form to disappear from all site pages after submit

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

This form exists in all the site pages. It should disappear after the first submit.
I want a new version of this code using a basic feature of browsers

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'subscribe.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        email : $("#inputemail").val()
    }
    success: function() {
        alert('Merci!')
    }
});

$("close").click(function(){
    $("#subscribe").hide();
});
```

```html
<div id="subscribe" style="display:block">
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="inputemail"/>
<input type="submit" value="Ok" />
<span id="close">Fermer</span>
</div>
```

Comment: to confirm, you're wanting to achieve this without jQuery?

Comment: yes, using a basic browser's functionality

Comment: by basic browser, do you mean, you need a solution with maximum support (ie for older browsers)?

Comment: Or, to phrase it differently: Why would you want to do it without jquery?

Comment: no, there is a basic feature of browsers that allows me to do the same work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then one approach to this would be to use the `XMLHttpRequest` object as an alternative to jQuerys `.ajax()` method. Using the configuration for `XMLHttpRequest` as shown below, you should find this script behaves the same way as your current jQuery dependant script.

Also, on a successful response (ie `status === 200`), this script will remove the `<div />` element that encloses your field/button from the document to achieve the desired "hiding" behaviour.

Although the newer `fetch()` API is generally preferred nowadays, the `XMLHttpRequest` object is used here to increase compatibility with older/basic browsers (as seems to be your requirement):

```js
var div = document.getElementById('subscribe');
var email = document.getElementById('inputemail');
var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
var close = document.getElementById('close');

if(getCookie('hasSubmit')) {
    div.remove();
}

submit.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  
  event.preventDefault();
    
  // Use xhr request for maximum compatbility with basic browsers
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  
  
  xhr.open("POST", 'subscribe.php', true);  
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() { 
  
    // If the post is successful
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status === 200) { 
      // then remove (hide) the div
      div.remove();
      setCookie('hasSubmit', 'true', 365);
    }
  }
  
  // Send the post request
  xhr.send("email=" + email.value); 
});

close.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    div.remove();
});

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    var expires = "expires="+d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

```html
<div id="subscribe" style="display:block">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" id="inputemail"/>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Ok" />
  <span id="close">Fermer</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I will just add that he probably needs to store the fact that the form was submitted in either a cookie or localStorage because the form will reappear on refresh or navigating to another page :)

Comment: @ArberSylejmani good point - just updated answer (though in sandbox mode, access to cookies appears to be disabled)

Comment: I don't know how much control he has over his code, but if it was me I would rather do the opposite, show the form only if the cookie was missing instead of having to div.remove() on every refresh.

Comment: @ArberSylejmani yes I agree - I had wondered about a "hidden by default" approach, but seeing `style="display:block"` suggests to me the form is initially shown, and perhaps there is not much control over this.